# Avoid warning for "uncaughtExceptionHandler" in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I am using the following code snippet in my `AppDelegate.m` to catch exceptions:

```
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"CRASH: %@", exception);
    NSLog(@"Stack Trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
}
```

How can I avoid this warning:

`Semantic Issue: No previous prototype for function 'uncaughtExceptionHandler`'?

Comment: That's a C function, not an Objective-C method.  Should it be?

Comment: Declare it as static. Full explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216498/492405

Comment: Thank you for the references, they helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare this method in the .h file

`void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException * exception);`

or place this function over the calling function.

```
    void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception){
       //your code
    }

- 

(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

            NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);
//your code

return YES;

}
```