# Error Handling on IOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, error-handling

How to handle the Errors/Exception in IOS when the app is crashing ?

Please advice on send the error logs to email from the IOS app ?

Is it any third party software to track IOS apps ?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12215012/1228534

Comment: Try [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) from Twitter.

Comment: If you need some tracking features, including tracking of your app crashes, you can also try [Google analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/). It's very easy to integrate in any app and gives a lot of statistics.

Answer (score 3):

Third party services is actually what you need:

- [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/) (I recommend it)
- [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-crash-analytics.html) has it's own crash reporting feature
- [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) has it's own crash reporting feature
- [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/)
- [PLCrashReporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/) it is library for handling app crashes

And many others.