# Uncaught Error/Exception Handling in Swift

Tags: swift, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I know there is an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215012/register-uncaughtexceptionhandler-in-objective-c-using-nssetuncaughtexceptionhan) in Cocoa, However I am looking for same thing for Swift. i.e. whenever there is any error/exception in application which is not caught locally there due to any mistake, it should bubble all the way to the top level application object where I should be able to gracefully handle it and respond to user appropriately.

[Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897628/need-to-handle-uncaught-exception-and-send-log-file) has it. [Flex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html) has it. [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) has it. Wondering why Swift is missing this key feature.

Comment: NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler is available is Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift. However, it catches only Objective-C exceptions, not Swift runtime errors or `throw`n errors.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for your quick reply. I know about NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler that it handles Objective-C exceptions. However I am looking for same/similar thing for Swift.

Comment: Swift has no mechanism to catch all kind of runtime errors. I can only guess about the reason. For example it wouldn't work well with automatic reference counting. You may be able to get a better response from the Swift developers on one of the mailing lists at swift.org.

Comment: Thanks again @MartinR... Do you know if event/exceptions/errors go through tunneling & bubbling phases in Swift .. I am just thinking if exceptions go through tunneling or bubbling phases, i could catch an exception at application level AppDelegate.

Comment: @SunnyTambi Nice question have you got any workaround ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Swift has no mechanism to catch all arbitrary runtime exceptions.
The reasons are explained in

- [[swift-users] "business applications market" flame](https://forums.swift.org/t/prototyping-what-swift-can-look-like-in-educational-settings/929/59)

in the swift-users forum. Extract:

> Swift made a conscious choice not to include exceptions thrown through
>   arbitrary stack frames not because it was technically impossible, but
>   because its designers judged the costs to be too high.
>
> The problem is this: if a piece of code is going to exit early because
>   of an error, it has to be written to handle that early exit. Otherwise
>   it will misbehave—fail to deallocate memory, fail to close file
>   handles/sockets/database connections/whatever, fail to release locks,
>   etc. In a language like Java, writing truly exception-safe code
>   requires a ridiculous quantity of try/finally blocks. That's why
>   nobody does it. They make judgements about which exceptions they're
>   likely to see and which resources are dangerous to leak, and only
>   protect their code against those specific anticipated conditions. Then
>   something unforeseen happens and their program breaks.
>
> This is even worse in a reference-counted language like Swift because
>   correctly balancing the reference counts in the presence of exceptions
>   basically requires every function to include an implicit finally block
>   to balance all the retain counts. This means the compiler has to
>   generate lots of extra code on the off chance that some call or
>   another throws an exception. The vast majority of this code is never,
>   ever used, but it has to be there, bloating the process.
>
> Because of these problems, Swift chose not to support traditional
>   exceptions; instead, it only allows you to throw errors in
>   specially-marked regions of code. But as a corollary, that means that,
>   if something goes really wrong in code that can't throw, all it can
>   really do to prevent a disaster is crash. And currently, the only
>   thing you can crash is the entire process.

For more information, see

- [Error Handling Rationale and Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ErrorHandlingRationale.rst)

Comment: Thanks @MartinR ... I found that Swift guys has offloaded the burden of handling every single small or big exception and error to the developers "by design".

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing, now at least the rationale is clear for what seemed like a puzzling omission.

Comment: This is fine with me, but I still need to at least be able to catch the signals so that I can implement my crash logger. Can't seem to make it work though; force unwrapping nil throws an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` that I'm unable to catch with either exception or signal handlers...

Answer (score 18):

This is the code I use to log all exceptions/errors. `Log.error(with:)` is a custom function where I store the stack trace, along with other info. `Thread.callStackSymbols` is an array of strings and represents the stack trace.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
        Log.error(with: Thread.callStackSymbols)
    }

    signal(SIGABRT) { _ in
        Log.error(with: Thread.callStackSymbols)
    }

    signal(SIGILL) { _ in
        Log.error(with: Thread.callStackSymbols)
    }

    signal(SIGSEGV) { _ in
        Log.error(with: Thread.callStackSymbols)
    }

    signal(SIGFPE) { _ in
        Log.error(with: Thread.callStackSymbols)
    }

    signal(SIGBUS) { _ in
        Log.error(with: Thread.callStackSymbols)
    }

    signal(SIGPIPE) { _ in
        Log.error(with: Thread.callStackSymbols)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, did not even know about signal(...) function

Comment: Note that only "async-signal safe" functions are safe to be called from within signal handlers. "printf" and related functions are not async-signal safe.

Comment: Where you use this code? AppDelegate? main? I've tried to add this code to my app without success.

Comment: @GuyKahlon I use it in AppDelegate, inside the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me (a MacOS application)

Comment: `let x = [1];
        print(x[5])` is NOT caught, any chance with swift error handling ?

Comment: @GuyKahlon its working on iOS. On macOS app its not working. any other way to achieve on Mac?

Comment: @andrei could you share your `Log.error` function? It looks useful!

Comment: Is this can co-exist with Crashlytics?