# Sandbox Swift code in a controlled environement, error safe

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

When working on a Swift **library** for **iOS**, you would you sandbox the library so an error in this library will not be repercuted in the host application? (= uncaught error will not crash the app)

Here are some clue that don't cover everything perfectly:

- using `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`: only catch Obj-c exception (NSException)
- using background queue with try/catch and closure, such as [here](https://appventure.me/2015/06/19/swift-try-catch-asynchronous-closures/).

The disered behavior can compare to Android where you could have one Thread and have an `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` on it so everything going wrong here will be catched.

*There may be no proper solution except try/catching everything because of the design of the language (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38738365/1377145)).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, in iOS you will throw an exception for situations where it is no longer safe to continue. For example, if the host application passing along bad initialization data to your library you should crash as it's undefined behavior to continue running.

As it turns out, crashing is only the third worst thing that you can do and as such you should do it rather than either of the two worse things.

#### Worst Things:

1. Corrupt user data
2. Hard to diagnose issues (undefined behavior, inconsistent behavior, etc)
3. Crash

It's perfectly fine to either crash, or use `throws` for methods which can fail, return `nil`, or return an `Error` object in a callback.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so for you try/catching and passing the error to the host app is a good idea?

Comment: Yes, it's good to give the host app a chance to respond to any errors appropriately (retry, display an error message, etc).