# how to catch an error efficiently in swift?

Tags: swift, try-catch

I need to catch a fatal error thrown from this code, the error is bellow,

```
let contents: Any?
do {
    contents = try Cstes.bufferECG_A.append(tmpECG)
} catch _ {
    contents = nil
    print("Catch the problem in Cstes.bufferECG_A")
}
```

error :

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x1c5430c80: pointer being freed was not 

allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

and the swift compiler tells me the advice bellow:

```
'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block
```

How can I make it work properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737880/uncaught-error-exception-handling-in-swift – You *cannot* catch arbitrary runtime exceptions in Swift.

Comment: You make it "work properly"  by fixing the code which caused the memory corruption.

Comment: So I cannot just say, it is an a memory error, catch it ?

Comment: No. It's in general not possible to recover from memory errors. Swift is memory-managed so, as a general rule, you should never see such errors -- unless you mess up (by using unsafe API without being very careful).