# Swift doesn't propagate fatal exceptions

Tags: swift, exception, try-catch

If I have two functions `A()` and `B()` where `A` calls `B`. Now if an exception is thrown inside `B` why can't I easily catch it inside `A` using a try catch block in `A`.

```
func B () -> Void {
   // library code that triggers an unhandled fatal exception
}

func A () -> Void {
  do {
    try B()
  } catch {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

This is something very easily done in other languages such as Java/Scala/Javascript etc.

Comment: That has nothing to do with error propagation. "Index out of bounds" is a *runtime exception* and not a Swift error, it cannot be catched.

Comment: My question is not about index out of bounds specifically but its more on the lines of how to gracefully handle any exception in swift code.

Comment: But the answer still applies, you cannot catch "any exception" in Swift, only *errors* which are (explicitly) *thrown.* See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737880/uncaught-error-exception-handling-in-swift.