# does swift 4 support exception handling?

Tags: swift, exception

My Swift program is crashing, to handle the crash is their any way, i tried  Exception handling i didn't got it, Does swift 4 supports Exception handling, what i want to do is i don't want my app to be crashed

here is the code i want to catch when ever i don't got the price value

```
let srt = self.Coin[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
var sr2=NSDictionary()
var barr  = NSArray()

if srt.value(forKey: "Price") != nil{
    do{
        barr = try srt.value(forKey: "Price") as! NSArray
        if (barr.count>0) {
            sr2 = barr[0] as! NSDictionary
        }
    } catch {
        print("Price is empty")
    }
}
```

Comment: `if let barr = srt.value(forKey: "Price") as? NSArray { ... }` might be a safer bet

Comment: `Does swift 4 supports Exception handling` No. But it supports Do-Try-Catch for errors (not exceptions). Read the Swift ebook, everything is explained.

Comment: Related: [Uncaught Error/Exception Handling in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38737880/1187415)

Comment: Another option is of course to avoid possible runtime errors by **not** doing forced unwrapping and forced casting even if it means having to write one or two extra lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Not all errors can be caught in Swift. `do-catch` blocks can only handle errors thrown by throwable functions, whose declarations are marked using the `throws` keyword and errors that are explicitly thrown from inside those functions using the `throw` keyword.

All other errors in Swift are uncatchable, especially runtime errors caused by force unwrapping, force casting or force try (`try!`). When you use `!` to force something, you tell the compiler that you know what you are doing and that a runtime error should be thrown in case an error occurs.

You shouldn't use force unwrapping/casting unless you are absolutely sure they won't fail or if you want to catch programming errors early in the development stage. Instead of using useless `do-catch` blocks with nested forced statements, simply use optional binding to safely cast/unwrap optional values.

Moreover, don't use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` in Swift, use their native equivalents, `Dictionary` and `Array`. It seems like you are parsing JSON, so use `[String:Any]` instead of `NSDictionary` and `[[String:Any]]` instead of `NSArray`.

```
if let srt = self.Coin[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any] {
    if let barrs = srt["Price"] as? [[String:Any]], let barr = barrs.first {
    let sr2 = barr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As David said, I'd avoid force unwrapping and force casting.
But instead of an `if let` statement, I'd rather use a `guard let` in order to avoid the *pyramid of doom*, like this:

```
 guard let srt = self.Coin[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any], let barr = srt["Price"] as? [[String:Any]], let sr2 = barr.first as? [String:Any] else {
        print("Price is empty")
        //Need to return, throw or whatever
    }
```

And we can even remove your intermediate variables, but it's much less readable, like so:

```
 guard let sr2 = ((self.Coin[indexPath.row] as? [String : Any])?["Price"] as? [[String : Any]])?.first as? [String : Any] else {
        print("Price is empty")
        //Need to return, throw or whatever
    }
```

If you'd rather go with the `if let` statement (in case you don't want to return or throw in your `guard` statement's `else` clause) you can also do it with a single `if` statement, like that

```
 if let srt = self.Coin[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any], let barr = srt["Price"] as? [[String:Any]], let sr2 = barr.first {
        //Do something with sr2
    }
```

And a shorter version without intermediate variables:

```
if let sr2 = ((self.Coin[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any])?["Price"] as? [[String:Any]])?.first {
        //Do something with sr2
    }
```

Whatever you choose... Don't force unwrap. Don't force try. Don't force cast. It will come back to bite you some day.