# Is it possible to make a global crash handler in swift? and How?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a global crash handler so that i can show message to users.
 Crashes like 
1. when value is **nil**(Force unwrap)
2. Unexpected **datatype**.

Comment: These kinds of crashes are hard crashes. They will get your application into a state that is not recoverable. That means you won't be able to show anything to your users.

Comment: Both of those issues are the result of bad coding practices and not understanding the basics of Swift. You're supposed to improve your coding, not search for hacks.

Comment: Related: [Uncaught Error/Exception Handling in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38737880/1187415).

Comment: Of course by not doing forced unwrap or forced casting those crashes can be avoided and proper error handling can be used instead

Answer (score 0):

No. A crash, by definition, means the program cannot continue executing.