# iOS swift CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont vs CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, core-graphics, core-text

I am using `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` to register `CGFont` loaded at runtime from various  sources (files, memory, ..), but some fonts raises an Exception with the following message:

```
Exception: "*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]"
```

an alternative to `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` is `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL`:
using this function I did not have any exception raised.

My Questions:

1. What is the cause of this behavior difference
2. How to catch & discard the exception raised by `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont`
3. Is there any thing to be done before calling `CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont` to prevent the exception.
4. What `.persistent` scope mean for 2nd parameter in `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL`.

Comment: 2. You can't catch all exception. There is a kind, and I suspect that one of being one that you can't catch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737880/uncaught-error-exception-handling-in-swift If you show you code, we might find where the issue is?

Comment: @Larme the thrown exception is an objective-c exception, and I was able to catch it on the simulator with a helper function, failed to do so on a real device.