# iOS Simple Crash detection

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I am trying to get simple crash detection working. Ten years ago was that no problem with Obj-C thanks to the UncaughtExceptionHandler. But Swift needs more work and I am not sure I am on the right path.

I tried the following implementation using signals, based on other approaches and comments. To my surprise my handlers seem not to get called. Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong?

```
import Foundation

class CrashDetection: NSObject {
    private static let observedSignals = [SIGABRT, SIGILL, SIGSEGV, SIGFPE, SIGBUS, SIGPIPE, SIGTRAP]
    private static var previousSignalHandlers: [Int32:(@convention(c) (Int32) -> Void)] = [:]

    @objc class func start() {
        NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(CrashDetection.recieveException)
        observedSignals.forEach { signalType in
            let oldHandler = signal(signalType, CrashDetection.recieveSignal)
            CrashDetection.previousSignalHandlers[signalType] = oldHandler
        }
    }

    private static let recieveException: @convention(c) (NSException) -> Swift.Void = {
        (recieveException) -> Void in
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "crashDidOccur")
    }

    private static let recieveSignal: @convention(c) (Int32) -> Void = {
        (recievedSignal) -> Void in
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "crashDidOccur")
        NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(nil)
        observedSignals.forEach { signalType in
            signal(signalType, previousSignalHandlers[signalType])
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I found this question and answer from 2016 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737880/uncaught-error-exception-handling-in-swift I think it still applies, but I'm not going to vote to close as a duplicate because I've already written an answer and, in any case, the given answer uses non-async signal safe functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you, but this comment needs more space than is available in comments.

I am not at all surprised that this isn't working for you. There are a number of problems with using signal handlers from Swift.

1. I would be extremely surprised if the code that is executed in `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(:, forKey:)` is async signal safe. If the key doesn't already exist, you will definitely be doing memory allocation, which means you risk corrupting the heap.
2. `SIG_IGN` and `SIG_DFL` are defined thus:

   ```
    #define SIG_DFL         (void (*)(int))0
    #define SIG_IGN         (void (*)(int))1
   ```

   They are not real functions. If the current signal handler is either one of those, you can't just call it.
3. On modern systems, the result of doing anything in a signal handler may not be immediately apparent outside of it. I assume this is because signals aren't necessarily handled on the same core and there are caching issues. I found the only way to reliably change a variable in a signal handler so the outside world could see it was to use an atomic operation.

I did once write a [signal handling API](https://bitbucket.org/jeremy-pereira/cltest/src/master/) for Swift so that I could detect <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> mainly. All the low level work was done in C and it still took me ages to get it to work (mainly because of the memory barrier problem).

You may have some luck using [DispatchSourceSignal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsourcesignal) although I'd be doubtful if that will work with segmentation violations.